# comparing the numbers and collecting details and providing output to new file

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression, perl

**file1** contains many numbers like shown below:

```
345656565465
783329439432
345656565465
783329439432
.......
```

**file2**:

```
345656565465;ram;dfdfdf54532fdf;...............................
783329439432;sam;dfsdgg543546fg;...............................
768737228732;bheem;dfsdg5465464767g;...........................
34565656546575;hema;jsdsds45345455h;..........................
```

Desired Output: **file1** should search the map in **file2** and put in **file3** (output) like this:

```
345656565465;ram;dfdfdf54532fdf;...............................
783329439432;sam;dfsdgg543546fg;...............................
```

So far, I've tried this:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{c[$1$2]++;next};c[$1$2] > 0' file2 file1
```

Also tried using perl but I'm not sure if this is correct or not since it's not giving me my desired output:

```
perl -e 'open(A, "file2"); while(<A>){/.+?\|[^|]+/ && $k{$&}++};
while(<>){/.+?\|[^|]+/ && do{print if defined($k{$&})}}' file1
```

The problems I am facing with is that it should grep only that number but in my codes it is taking the big-number which consists the same pattern 
and it should paste in third file. please help me to achieve this :)

Comment: The answer to "Can you suggest me a better code?" can only be "Yes" or "No" Please update your post by indicating what the output of your `awk` and `perl` "solutions" and what is wrong with those. Also provide a real question (which has no Yes/No answer)

Comment: by using AWK i am getting this output  this is different from desired output.              783329439432;sam;dfsdgg543546fg;48384738473847983423433433;jkshsadhasjhdjsad;jhf‌​sdkjhfs;jdhsjd 783329439432;sam;dfsdgg543546fg;48384738473847983423433433;jkshsadhasjhdjsad;jhf‌​sdkjhfs;jdhsjd 783329439432;sam;dfsdgg543546fg;48384738473847983423433433;jkshsadhasjhdjsad;jhf‌​sdkjhfs;jdhsjd

Comment: What part of "update your post" is unclear to you?

Answer (score 1):

you almost make it

```
awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next ;} c[$1] > 0' file1 file2
```

where

- `-F';'` use semi colon as separator (and not pipe)
- use `file1` first to catch number
- I suppose you want to select on first column.

Comment: i tried yours also, but i got following output 783329439432;sam;dfsdgg543546fg;48384738473847983423433433;jkshsadhasjhdjsad;jhfsdkjhfs;jdhsjd                                                                                  
783329439432;sam;dfsdgg543546fg;48384738473847983423433433;jkshsadhasjhdjsad;jhfsdkjhfs;jdhsjd                                                                                  
783329439432;sam;dfsdgg543546fg;48384738473847983423433433;jkshsadhasjhdjsad;jhfsdkjhfs;jdhsjd

Comment: yes i want to compare with first column :)